# Prolog: Reflect (X,Y) -> (Y,X)

Tags: prolog

I am attempting to generate a second, reflected point besides the input in prolog without using Inbuilt functions (i.e. swap etc).

I am unsure how to swap these without causing infinite recursion by defining each in terms of the other.

This is what I have tried here.

```
reflection(X,Y) :- point(X,Y),point(Y,X).

point(X,Y).
```

Correct for: 
reflection(point(1,2), point(2,1).

But It will not correctly answer:

reflection(point(-5, 8), point(X, Y)),
        writeln(point(X, Y))...

Expect(8,-5), Returns random(~) large integers (prolog standard)

Comment: You haven't provided us all of your code. What you have shown does not produce the output you're suggesting.

Comment: The goal `reflection(point(-5, 8), point(X, Y))` unifies with `reflection(point(-5, 8),point(X, Y)) :- point(point(-5,8),point(X, Y)),point(point(X, Y),point(-5,8)).` which isn't making much sense.

Comment: let's start with what language/implementation *specifically* are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You program is simply this clause.

```
reflection(point(X, Y), point(Y, X)).
```

And querying with `reflection(point(-5, 8), point(X, Y)), writeln(point(X, Y)).` yields:

```
point(8, -5)

X = 8,
Y = -5
```

Comment: @Smiley Flower - Did this answer your question?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you very much! It makes sense that we can declare predicates this way/

Comment: You are welcome! Do not forget to accept the answer.